# Alcanzaste tu límite de preguntas

Tags: discusión

hoy he querido hacer una pregunta en Stack Overflow a lo que al intentar formular la pregunta me dijo : Alcanzaste tu límite de preguntas.

Como puedo resolver ese problema???

Comment: tienes muchas preguntas sin respuesta... ve a cada una y las que tengas respuesta marcalas como respondidas...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso eso no es cierto, el aceptar o no respuestas es independiente a la hora de recibir este aviso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es en realidad un límite de preguntas , lo que sucede es que has realizado publicaciones consideradas de baja calidad y el sistema te generó un bloqueó temporal para formular preguntas.

Por está razón es muy importante formular preguntas en base a [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que la pregunta sea bien recibida y evitar este tipo de problemas.

Comment: Que tiempo dura el bloqueo?

Comment: @Osdward Dura hasta que mejores tu ratio de preguntas mal recibidas con las de bien recibidas. No es algo que podamos mover nosotros. Es algo que tenes que manejar vos mismo. Todas las preguntas (o la gran mayoria) deben tener respuestas, asi sean tuyas o de otros. Tene en cuenta que eliminar preguntas no te sirve, porque para calcular esto, tambien se toman las preguntas eliminadas. Tambien intenta que las mismas esten bien formuladas y sean claras de forma de poder ser respondidas.

Comment: @Jorgesys Como un usuario con reputación creciente y sin votos en contra recibe un bloqueo de tal tipo ?? Son preguntas eliminadas por el mismo OP ??

Comment: @Excorpion lo que sucede es que Osdward elimino algunas de estas publicaciones, como comenta Gonzalo, tambièn se toman en cuenta las publicaciones eliminadas.

Comment: Ahh entonces es como me paso a mi en el sitio en inglés. @Osdward, en este caso, el bloqueo dura hasta que las preguntas mejoren, o pase un letargo, no se cuanto fue el mio, pero el caso es similar.

Comment: Esperar hasta que me desbloquen entonces.